# How to Create your own JSON parser library in python

Tags: python

Question asked to me in an Interview.
To write a Library in python which can parse the JSON data.
It can be a JSONObject or JSON String or anything else.
It should be able to handle all the types of data types
example JSON Data

```
  {
    "name": "JaneDoe",
    "age": 42,
    "smoking": false,
    "education": {
        "school": "abcSchool",
        "University": "xyz"
    },
    "certificates": ["ccna", "python", "aws"],
    "salary": 4200.0,
    "profile_img": "https://ii.abc.com/jpeg/profiles/jane.jpg"
}
```

Comment: `import json as my_own_parser_library`

Comment: You need to start by reading the JSON specification as mentioned in one of the answer. Then you need to have some knowledge of object-oriented programming to do it right and efficient. You may also wanna look into _regular expressions_ since you'd need to find specific strings in a text and parse them. Don't forget to validate your JSON object before doing this all. Your example JSON object isn't valid btw! One shortcut is to look at the source code of `json` or `simplejson` library.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.json.org/json-ru.html gives all you need to start - there are simple block diagrams, showing how to parse different supported types, like this:

[image]

So just rewrite them in Python